# LM317 construct 3volt output and 2amp output

Tags: power-supply

I am doing a project using 6 stepper motors. These motors have different operating voltage and current. For example, one requires 3.6V and 2A, another one requires 2.4V and 1.2A. The 6 stepper motors operating in different voltages and current, so I purchased a 12 Volt 2 Amp transformer, (6 numbers) and a LM317. I also purchased a stepper motor L298 H bridge driver.

Now my doubt is how to reduce the voltage from 12V to 3V using the LM317? I don't need to reduce the current. I need 2A 3V output from my transformers. Please help me.

Comment: I edited for grammar, but to be sure @sureshkumar, I believe you mean that you purchased 6 (six) 12V power adaptors, and 6 LM317 regulators as well, is that correct?

Comment: Please edit your question to list all of the motors and their voltages and currents.

Comment: @kaz - that information is not necessary to the question.  What is needed is an understanding of the methods used to drive stepper motors, in particular why voltages far in excess of nameplate are used.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - NOTHING is ever "necessary". But giving all available data on motor specs is really a minimum as there may be "gotcha's" that a beginner does not recognise. Pulsed stepper motor drive to achieve ~= constant current drive is of course superior - but we now have a beginner who had trouble wading in the shallow end but has now been thrown in to the deep(er) end.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are focusing on your questiong about configuring the LM317 correctly. However, I'd rather go for your intent.

Just because the stepper motor nameplate says it runs at "2.4V @ 2A" does not mean that is exactly required. It really means that at a supply voltage of 2.4V, it will draw 2A.

You can run the motor at a higher voltage (IME it's rare to run at nameplate voltage) and this will provide better high speed performance, however you must limit the current to avoid motor overheating. So if you run your "2.4V" motor at 12 volts, either a power resistor must be used inline with the motor coil, or a current limit driver must be used instead of your L293. Using a resistor is often called the "L/R" method.

Let's say we wanted to keep your motor running on 4.8 watts (2.4 * 2) from a 12V power supply. We'd want to reduce the current to 0.4A. That would mean a 48 ohm resistor (50ohm is close standard value) with a 2W rating. Motor will likely run much smoother.

It is worth investigating more modern drive IC's than the L293 that incorporate a current-limiting chopper drive. But as a start, the L/R method is fine.

Comment: The L297, intended to be used with the L298, has chopping current regulation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to directly regulate the 12 V down to 3.6 V or 2.4 V that the stepper motors are intended to run at.  Drive the stepper motor coils with PWM with a duty cycle so that the average is still within the motor's rating.  The coils will be driven with lots of 12 V pulses in rapid succession, but if this is done fast enough they will only "see" the average.  A few 100 Hz should be enough for the motor to react only to the average, but you probably want more than that so that the coils themselves, which look like inductors to the driving electronics, average the current thru them nicely.  Usually this is done a bit above the audible frequency range.

For example, let's say you are using pulses at 25 kHz.  That's 40 µs per pulse.  If each pulse is on for 10 µs and off for 30 µs, then the coil will be effectively driven with the average of 3 V.

Another very nice feature of this scheme is that the losses will be low.  With a linear regulator like the LM317, current in is current out, which will be horribly inefficient with 12 V in and 3 V out.  By pulsing the coils, you are much closer to power in is power out (minus a little loss).  Put another way, you are making a switching power supply for each coil, just that the coil itself is a integral part of the switching power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Linear regulators reduce voltage by acting like a resistor.

Reworking Kaz's solution a bit: even if the application were correct (which there are doubts), the LM317 is not going to work, since at 9V differential (12V-3V) and 25°C, assuming TO-220 and derating \$T_{J(max)}\$ by 20 degrees for reliability reasons:

\$ P_{max} = \dfrac{T_{J(MAX)} - T_A}{\theta_{JA}} \$

\$ P_{max} = \dfrac{130°C - 25°C}{\frac{19°C}{W}} \$

\$ P_{max} = 5.5W \$

\$ I_{max} = \dfrac{5.5W}{9V} = 611mA \$

611mA isn't going to work where 2A is needed. The device will thermally shut down.

Answer (score 0):

2A is a bit high for most LM317's.
Look at datasheet for your model.
LM350 is high current big brother.

12V is FAR TOO HIGH a voltage if you want 3.6, 2.4, 3V etc.
Vdc loaded needs to be about Vout+2.5V so eg 3.6V+2.5 = 6.1V = 6V for the 3V6 output.

A 5VAC transformer is closer to what you want.
Vdc loaded ~~~~ 1.4 x VAC.   Here 5V x 1.4V = 7V so allowing for some droop and wiring loss and ripple then 5VAC is about right.

Dissipation in regulator is (Vin - Vout) x Iload.
So at 2A if you have 3.6V out and 12VDC in at 2A dissipation =
 (Vin-Vo) x Iload = (12-3.6) x 2A = 16.8 Watts.
 A good heatsink is needed.

Using 5VAC to make Vin is better.

Comment: This is not, however, a very good solution for powering a stepper motor.  Chopping current regulation is much better, to allow the higher available voltage to be used to overcome winding inductance at high step rates.

Answer (score 0):

2A of current deliver is close to the limit for the 317, and you have a large drop from 12V to 3V. This asks the 317 to dissipate a lot: \$2A\times 9V = 18W\$! This is not going to happen with any heat sink, and so the 317 will just shut down the current and lose regulation.

The [TI datasheet says](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)(P. 2 footnotes) that \$P_D = (T_J(max) – T_A)/\theta_{JA}\$.  \$\theta_{JA}\$ is given for the TO-220 package as 19°C/W.  \$T_J(max)\$ (the absolute one, not the recommended one) is 150°C.   So we can take \$P_D\$ to be 18W and solve for \$T_A\$: ambient temperature:

$$T_A = T_J(max) - P_D\theta_{JA}$$

$$T_A = 150 - 18W \times 19°C/W$$

$$T_A = 150 - 342$$

$$T_A = -187°C$$

So if we achieve a cryogenic ambient temperature \$T_A\$, or an equivalent heat sink, we can have 18W of dissipation.

Comment: I was looking at datasheets for the LM317, most have (with proper heatsinking, and VIN - Vout <= 15V) the minimum current out at 1.5A, BUT Typical current out for the common To-220 package to be 2.2A, (TI, On-Semi, Fairchild). The TI has a listed max of 3.4A, but then contradicts itself. Any idea what is the max?

Comment: In the ON Semi one there is a footnote about a maximum 20W power dissipation. But that must require very good heat sinking because maximum dissipation is just that: no derating for temperature. There is no maximum current published; you are only given a minimum.

Comment: Look at TI's datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf) page 5. For the NDE package (to-220) it shows 3.4A max, but then note (1) below it shows Imax 1.5A.

Comment: Ah, I'm looking at the different version: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf

Comment: The TI lm317.pdf document clarifies that the 1.5 min and 2.2 typical currents are in fact for a maximum Vin - Vout difference as high as 15V.

Comment: Okay, so how are we to interpret that 3.4? I would take it as just that: the maximum current you can obtain, when Vin-Vout is somewhere in the range 15V or less. It doesn't necessarily mean **at** 15V. The maximum current would occur at the **lowest** possible dropout at which regulation still takes place (or so I'm interpreting it). This is useful to know: it means that if we optimize the input voltage, the most we can expect is 3.4A.

Comment: I hate when TI doesn't differentiate between minor part numbers. I can't find a difference between the LM317, LM317A, and LM317N. But even on your datasheet, the Max output current still shows 1.5 A min, 2.2 A typical, but a little above that, the "Recommended" (but not Absolute Maximum section) is 1.5A max.

Comment: This is not, however, a very good solution for powering a stepper motor.  Chopping current regulation is much better, to allow the higher available voltage to be used to overcome winding inductance at high step rates.

Comment: "Minimum" maximum output current refers to the lowest current that the device will deliver without protecting itself - it's the lower bound for the internal current limit. It does NOT mean that the device must operate at that minimum current.